# Unable to Open Session for VM

Tags: linux, macos, virtual-machine

I recently bought CompTIA's Linux+ certification book and am going through the process of importing the provided .ova file to follow along with the material in the book.

The .ova imports successfully, but I am unable to open a session. I receive the following error message:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Template  Linux Exam XK0-004 .

The virtual machine 'Template  Linux Exam XK0-004 ' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}
```

I am running macOS Big Sur v11.2.3 with the Apple M1 chip, and I am using Oracle VM VirtualBox v6.1.18.

The tutorial .pdf for importing the .ova recommends using v6.0.14 but I was unable to install that version onto my device.

Does anyone have any suggestions on fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox is an **x86** virtualization hypervisor. It currently only runs on an x86 platform. See https://www.virtualbox.org

While Rosetta 2 will run many x86 apps very well on an M1 Mac, virtualization products are not supported per this [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/about-the-rosetta-translation-environment)